# ASP.NET MVC или Python Django

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, python, django

Добрый вечер. Я собираюсь создать веб приложение с повышенной нагрузкой. И сейчас у меня стоит выбор инструмента, но определиться я не как не могу. Обе технологии я знаю на должном уровне, и обе отлично подходят под мою задачу. Скрипт приложения будет стоять на разных сайтах, получая код из моего скрипта из бд. В качестве базы данных я буду использовать Postgresql(даже в случае ASP.NET), так как Sql server по началу в финансах не потяну (но хотелось бы и по этому поводу что-нибудь услышать). В качестве серверной ОС скорее всего будет использоваться Windows Server 2008 R2(даже в случае с Python Django), возможно и линукс подобные, пока не решил точно. Подскажите пожалуйста плюсы и минусы. Спасибо.

Comment: "Скрипт приложения будет стоять на разных сайтах, получая код из моего скрипта из бд" - зачем так сложно? Всё будет выполняться в один поток или в несколько потоков/задач на каждом из серверов?

Comment: Я неправильно выразился. Скорее виджет. Пока сервер будет один, выделенный. Со временем будет отдельный сервер для базы данных, отдельный для логики и отдельный для статики на ngnix.

Comment: вот просто душой я за django, без комментариев=))

Comment: будет сервер БД, сервер приложений и сервер реализации бизнес-логики - правильно я понимаю?

Comment: python и django по мне проще запустить минимальную версию. Был у нас проект: сервер логики на Java, интерфейсная часть на C# (десктопное приложение). Сложновато было...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько "сравнений", типа этого: http://www.pythondiary.com/blog/Apr.11,2012/comparing-django-aspnet-mvc.html, но конкретики в них мало, да и сравнивать совершенно разные платформы сложно.

Точно можно сказать, что windows выйдет дороже. Дороже лицензия, дороже саппорт (Вы же не собираетесь нагруженный проект поддерживать сами вручную?). Абсолютно точно деплой python на винде будет неудобным и глючным (а деплоя asp на линуксе вообще не будет).

В остальном - берите то, что лучше знаете, что больше нравится, и для чего лучше представляете себе могущие возникнуть сложности. Хуже нет на большом проекте, чем упереться в неочевидный косяк технологии, которая выбрана маркетологами из-за "низкого ТСО".

Answer (score 3):

Предложение: python + django (вместе с gunicorn), ngnix, postgresql. ОС - можно хоть убунту взять на первом этапе (несложная настройка).

Если опишете задачу подробнее - можно порекомендовать какие-нибудь NoSQL БД (как правило, под конкретную задачу можно выбрать удачное решение).

Comment: Задачу рассказать не могу, это пока закрытый проект. Но можно взять например: существуют всякие системы комментариев, типа виджет комментариев ВК, на главном сайте пользователь настраивает виджет, получает код, и вставляет его в свой сайт. Код загружает виджет комментариев, и обеспечивает функционал сохранения и загрузки комментариев на мой сервер. Будет целая система с партнерской программой, API, статистикой, кастомизацией виджета и.т.д. Вот типа такой проект будет.

Comment: какой JS-фреймворк взять даже не подскажу... Если захотите представлять данные в виде графа, то можно взять Neo4j. Комментарии как документы можно хранить в MongoDB.

Comment: С клиентом проблем нет. В качестве базы, я все таки буду использовать клиент-серверные. Проблема выбора касалась лишь серверной технологии. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

я бы на вашем месте обратил внимание на другие питонофреймфорки такие как торнадо, твистед. по моему мнению, с джанги переучиться совсем несложно.